# Can i use page_messaging_subscription to send news that there's new promotion

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

According to facebook platform policy, we cannot send promotiona via page_message_subscription, however in the case that user intend to receive message regarding update in promotion for example in an subscribe to flash-deal. Can I send a news that there's a promotion updated and let user click to view the promotion (using normal page_messaging permission)

Comment: page_messaging only let you reply in 24 hours after the user messaged you. If you want to message the user after that you need page_message_subscription

Comment: Yes, im refering to using page_message_subscription to send update that there's some new promotion (if user opt-in to update) but not sending the promotion itself

Comment: If you want to know for sure, then you have to implement it and send it for review. But I doubt they will approve that; I can’t see it fitting into any of the three use cases/categories.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `pages_messaging_subscriptions` clearly states what are the allowed cases where you can send subscription messages:

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/08/15/updated-messenger-platform-policies#matrix)

> Eligible use cases include: News: Bots whose
>   primary purpose is to inform people about recent or important events
>   or information in categories such as sports, finance, business, real
>   estate, weather, traffic, politics, and entertainment. Productivity:
>   Bots whose primary purpose is to enable people to manage their
>   personal productivity with tasks such as managing calendar events,
>   receiving reminders, and paying bills. Personal trackers: Bots that
>   enable people to receive and monitor information about themselves in
>   categories such as fitness, health, wellness, and finance.

When you apply for approval Facebook are saying you have to specify in which of these use cases your app falls into. I don't see how you can place frequent promotional updates in any of these.

> No promotional content can be sent with subscription messaging. Subscription messaging is only intended for specific use cases and, at time of submission, businesses will need to indicate which use case their experience falls under.

I hope this helps. You can always comment on their [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/08/15/updated-messenger-platform-policies) and hope to get a better reply.